# Casting related invalid lvalue in unary &

Tags: c, gcc

I'm getting the invalid lvalue error using gcc 3.4.6. The line that invokes the error has a function that receives a pointer to SetElement (which is `typedef void*`). I'm trying to achieve this using casting from another type (also `typedef void*`) the following way: `&((SetElement)my_var)`. gcc complains about this. Any idea what can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the address of a temporary (an `rvalue`), which cannot be done.  This is like trying to do:

```
&(2+2)
// or
&4
// or
&(my_ptr + 4)
```

You can create a temporary yourself (thus an `lvalue`), using one of two methods:

```
AnotherType **my_var_ptr = &my_var;
SetElement **set_element_ptr = (SetElement *)my_var_ptr;

// or

SetElement *set_element = (SetElement)my_var;
SetElement **set_element_ptr = &set_element;
```

Or you can simply cast in a different way (**solution**):

```
SetElement **set_element_ptr = (SetElement *)&my_var;
```

This works because you're taking the address of `my_var` (an `lvalue`), and not of `(SetElement)my_var` (an `rvalue`).

Comment: Why is it a temporary address? And isn't there a way to do this directly?

Comment: It's temporary because you take an lvalue and cast it, turning it into an rvalue.  & expects an lvalue.  You can think of lvalue and rvalue as left- and right-hand parts of an assignment.  See my examples -- & is always used on an lvalue.

Comment: Also, I don't think there is a way to do this directly without a temporary.  If you take the address of a temporary, the temporary will be destroyed and your pointer will be invalid (pointing to nothing useful; undefined).

Comment: Ah, I just had an epiphany.  =]  Yes, you can do it in one line.  See my edit.

Comment: Since you've edited it, you may want to edit the paragraph that introduces it, too, since you have three, not two, and the student probably wants the first or second one.